# Weird behavior in Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, sleep

I have noticed something very odd (which eventually crashes my game) with `Thread.sleep()` and  I cannot figure out what the problem might be. I have run the following method for two hours straight and the output is always 100+-5;

```
public void gameLoop() {
    t0 = time();
    while (GameState.getInstance().getState() == GameCondition.RUNNING) {

        engine.update();
        sfx.play();

        t1 = time();
        delta = t1 - t0;

        gfx.render((int) delta);
        t0 = time();
        System.out.println(delta);
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Now if I run the exact same method but instead of sleeping for the constant 100 I sleep for `delta`

```
public void gameLoop() {
    t0 = time();
    while (GameState.getInstance().getState() == GameCondition.RUNNING) {

        engine.update();
        sfx.play();

        t1 = time();
        delta = t1 - t0;

        gfx.render((int) delta);
        t0 = time();
        System.out.println(delta);
        sleep(delta);
    }
}
```

And now the output reads:

```
0

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

2

....
 After a minute
 571
```

I don't know if I am too tired and have made an obvious mistake or something very weird is happening, here is the sleep.

```
private void sleep(long milliSeconds) {
    System.out.println();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(milliSeconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit: The problem? The delta is "leaking", since the inner methods (before the sleep) use virtually no time (as proven by the `sleep(100)` test) I expect delta to be very precise with minor to no fluctuations, yet it keeps growing.

Comment: I think your delta calculation is off. Basically `delta = t1 - t0;` is calculating the amount of time that it took to loop through your game loop, which, from the output, would be about a millisecond.  What you actually need to do is then substract the MAXIMUM wait time from this value.  For example, if you want 25fps, then you would need something like `delta = 40 - (t1 - t0);` which would give a MAXIMUM delta of 40 milliseconds or less, in order to maintain a average of 25fps...(don't forget to allow for negative values ;))

Comment: I am aware of that, this is just my test-setup, I do actually do what you are proposing in all of my (whole other two games :D). The problem  I have here is the curious behavior of sleep, it leaks.

Comment: 1) *"I have noticed something very odd (which eventually crashes my game) with `Thread.sleep()`"*  If this is a Swing/AWT app. the repaints should probably be triggered by a `java.swing.Timer` & there would thereafter be no need for `sleep(n)`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I am implementing active rendering http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html drawing directly on a canvas supported by a bufferstrategy so Swing/AWT paint calls are disabled.

Comment: It could be a scheduling issue.  Try increasing the delta slightly.  Anything less then 5-10 milliseconds is as good as having no sleep at all

Comment: I thought that too, sleep even has a warning about not depending too much on it due to how OS handles the event. But I ran sleep(1) for a few minutes now and it the sysout still prints "1" with no leakage.

Comment: Could there be some weird race condition here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop, your delta calculation encompasses the time previously slept, and then sleeps for this new delta time.  If sleep (or your code) is ever slow (say 1ms, which can happen) then your delta will be 1ms longer next time so you will sleep for 2ms.

Your next iteration, since you slept for 2ms last time, will be at least 2ms.  If sleep or your code is slow again (which will happen) then you will sleep for 3ms next time and so on.  You are accumulating all the slowness that might occur due to your delta including the previous sleep time and any error in it.

Comment: +1 got in right before me - also GC can have a part in making it "slow". Either way the sleeping time should be subtracted from a delta, not added to it.

Comment: @Pescis Agree on the GC issue (probably the culprit in fact).