# Why is my game lagging?

Tags: java, multithreading, timing, lag

I'm making a basic 2D game, yet I'm having problems with lag. The character on the game moves fine, yet sometimes slows right down, mainly when near an enemy. The enemy is not causing the lag though, as I've had 50 of them on the screen at once and it runs fine.
I've done the timing almost identically to how it's done in the Killer Game Programming in Java book, yet it doesn't seem to work too well. The FPS also seems to change a lot, which it shouldn't, because it should always take 15ms to complete an update-render-paint-sleep cycle, can anyone explain this?

Also, I think it lags more when my computer is doing things in the background (antivirus scanning, etc.), although I can run the game at about 550FPS while it's running other programs, so I don't think it's my computer.

Here's how I do the timing:

```
        int waitTime = 1000 / 65; //65 being the desired FPS
        while(running){
        if(!loading){
            gameUpdate();
            gameRender();
            gamePaint();

            afterTime = System.nanoTime();
            timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
            sleepTime = waitTime - (timeDiff / 1000000L);

            if(sleepTime > 0){
                try{
                    mainThread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch(InterruptedException ie){}
            }
            else{ 
                sleepSkipped++;
                if(sleepSkipped == maxSleepSkipped){
                    Thread.yield();
                    sleepSkipped = 0;
                }
            }

            fpsTime += (System.nanoTime() - beforeTime) / 1000000;
            fps++;
            if(fpsTime > 1000){
                System.out.println("FPS: " + fps);
                fps = 0;
                fpsTime = 0;
            }

            beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you do when near an enemy? Collision/Combat can have a bug, I see nothing wrong with your loop.

Comment: Each enemy checks for the player all the time. I would have the enemy check for the player only when they are near, but I can't. I'll have a good look at the collision detection though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to one very recently [Weird behavior in Thread.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960607/weird-behavior-in-thread-sleep) 
I see that in your loop you add the sleeptime to your timer, meaning it keeps increasing (lowering fps) until it becomes so large that substracting the waittime from it gives a negative number, making your loop go into the one that yields the thread where it adds to the skipcount and yields when the count is high enough.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my loop I make the thread sleep for a set time depending on how long the update, render and paint methods took. I'm not adding anything.

Comment: Try running http://www.fraps.com/ and seeing the FPS via that tool, I may be wrong though glad my first suggestion helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As arynaq suggested, it was a problem with the enemy collision detection. Every cycle through the loop made each enemy call quite a few methods, however I have now removed and relocated many of the method calls, which has completely fixed the lag problem. Thank you, arynaq.